Public IP Conflict
I am by no means a professional network engineer but I am currently facing a challenging situation and would appreciate any help given.
Situation:-

LAN is configured with a public IP address range (192.192.192.0/24) instead of a private IP range
There are also some systems, servers, printers, configs, etc that are set with static IPs
Will have a problem routing out to the "real" public IP 192.192.192.0/24 as router do not know if the request is directed towards LAN or WAN
The router's routing table will always route 192.192.192.0/24 locally
If we overwrite the route with a static route to point to the router's next hop (which is the ISP router) then the routing for LAN will have issues

General idea of the scenario
Theory-wise, can the LAN subnet of 192.192.192.0/24 route out to the real public IP of 192.192.192.0/24? If yes, what are the possible solutions that are cheap, easy and fast to resolve such issues?
Note that: we can't change the whole LAN subnet and can't afford fancy solutions such as Policy Base Routing (cause not all routers have PBR) which might not be scalable. Pure simplicity for the solution (if there's any).
I am currently thinking of virtual routing & forwarding, is it simple to apply and scalable?

hi @Ramhound, my WAN interface is in a different subnet. Let's say 56.56.56.56 and NAT is enabled on the router.

I miss read your diagram but you did say your addressing your LAN devices directly to the subnet you say was your public LAN address. Which sounds extremely odd but I won’t suggest something else is going on because I don’t feel like it

no worries @Ramhound, the LAN subnet configuration was actually done by someone else and now I'm trying to fix it. Normally how I see it is - ISP gives WAN IP, we set our own LAN's subnet and then NAT it out to WAN. But in this case the LAN's subnet was set to be in a public IP address range. (Sorry for any misinformation as I am still learning)

I would follow your instinct and make it like that, because it seems the previous guy did not know how to do things properly, or has some really weird config in mind that you need to understand first. Normally, WAN IP -> Router -> Private LAN.

hi @LPChip, thank you, that is to say in theory implementing VRF will allow packets to route locally (192.192.192.0/24) and route out to the internet (192.192.192.0/24) without any conflicts?
